# Is drag and drop and shared clipboard a way for a malware to escape a virtual machine or sandbox?

Tags: virtual-machine, malware, sandbox

Windows sandbox does it, you can enable them on many other virtual machine software too.

And I think in stuff like Sandboxie, the clipboard is shared too.

Answer (score 0):

The clipboard has to be monitored and the content possible to exploit the monitoring application, than yes, this would be possible.

But this sounds more like the idea whether or not malware can be inserted into a sandbox via the clipboard, if enabled. Then the answer is yes, this can be exploited.

Comment: How about drag and drop though?

Comment: It simply doesn't matter. The "Drag and Drop" is simply the clipboard, but integrated in the user operation. Technically, this is realized by the clipboard.

Comment: But can't a software simulate the drag and drop action from inside the virtual machine and take files to the outside?

Comment: Ah that's the root of your question. The Drag-and-Drop-Operation of the Virtual Machine Software can only be initiated on the Host machine, not the guest. So no, this is not exploitable by automatic "drag-and-drop".